# Cannot read configuration file \\?\D:\home\site\.well-known\web.config

Tags: azure, asp.net, web-applications, azure-app-services

I have a strange situation where a single ASP.NET Core Web App I am running on Azure is having issues serving files from a particular directory.

Specifically I am trying to serve a file from the path `https://myurl.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/6uVkXzXxHHkm1d6cQiUqI07lrYspInk7i9WCKKl-RlQ` I note that this is a slightly unusual url in that the filepath does not contain a file extension and the directory starts with a (.) this is a requirement outside my control.

Unfortunately while I can successfully get this working on nearly all my app service instances I have one where this is failing with the following error:

> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
> configuration data for the page is invalid. Config Error Cannot read configuration file \?\D:\home\site.well-known\web.config

My web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
   
    <modules>
      <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <!-- When deploying on Azure, make sure that "dotnet" is installed and the path to it is registered in the PATH environment variable or specify the full path to it -->
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="23:00:00" processPath=".\Nop.Web.exe" arguments="" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" startupTimeLimit="3600" hostingModel="InProcess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <!-- Protects against XSS injections. ref.: https://www.veracode.com/blog/2014/03/guidelines-for-setting-security-headers/ -->
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
        <!-- Protects against Clickjacking attacks. ref.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22105445/1233379 -->
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <!-- Protects against MIME-type confusion attack. ref.: https://www.veracode.com/blog/2014/03/guidelines-for-setting-security-headers/ -->
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <!-- Protects against Clickjacking attacks. ref.: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet -->
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" />
        <!-- CSP modern XSS directive-based defence, used since 2014. ref.: http://content-security-policy.com/ -->
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; connect-src *; font-src * data:; frame-src *; img-src * data:; media-src *; object-src *; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';" />
        <!-- Prevents from leaking referrer data over insecure connections. ref.: https://scotthelme.co.uk/a-new-security-header-referrer-policy/ -->
        <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="same-origin" />
        <!--Feature-Policy is a new header that allows a site to control which features and APIs can be used in the browser. ref.: https://wicg.github.io/feature-policy/ -->
        <add name="Feature-Policy" value="accelerometer 'none'; camera 'none'; geolocation 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; microphone 'none'; payment *; usb 'none'" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 4f1f649c-1020-45be-a487-f416d9297ff3-->
```

Based on the error it looks like for some reason ASP.NET is looking for a web.config file in my wwwroot directory. Anyone able to provide any guidance on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nearly as soon as I post the question I find the answer.

For anyone who runs into this issue the problem was that somehow I had mapped a virtual directory into this path for this application.

Once I removed this everything worked as expected.

[image]